# Need clarification on typealias syntax in Swift

Tags: swift, alias

Can someone explain why there is a ":" after the typealias "Generator" in the example below? Is it saying that "Generator" is conforming to "GeneratorType"? I am confused because when I read the Swift documentation, it only describes an "=" sign after an alias name.

```
protocol SequenceType : _Sequence_Type {
    typealias Generator : GeneratorType
    func generate() -> Generator
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a protocol, `typealias` declares an [associated type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID189). Classes and structures that conform to this protocol must have a `typealias` directive that declares the type to something concrete.

Yes, it means that `Generator` must conform to `GeneratorType` in any implementation of the `SequenceType` protocol.

Comment: Thank you! I was hesitant on what the colon ":" meant in terms of a typealias.